# Export POD format from 3D Max to cocos3D

Tags: iphone, cocoapods, 3dsmax, cocos3d

we're developing a Medical app with a 3D character thats teachs about phisioterapy.

We have a 3D character in 3D Studio Max with animation, when export it into POD (I Have tried many configurations) the character deforms their volumes when I preview in PVRShaman. If I check export matrices options everything its ok excepts that the character doesn't animate in iOS emulator (Also it appears upside down).

We're using

- cocos3d 0.7.1
- 3D Studio Max 2012
- Last PVRTOPOD export plugin
- iOS 5.1.1
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64Bits.

Does anyone has same problem or any solution? it's driving me crazy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [www.gameplay3d.org](http://www.gameplay3d.org). We think our solution is very clean and doesn't try to rely on a baseline architecture like cocos2d which is not the best way to start an architecture for a 2D framework or engine.

It is better not to build a '3D' framework/engine based on a 2D engine architecture. The gameplay frmework is cross-platform and very well tested by my team. Supports Windows, MacOSX, iOS, Android and BlackBerry :)